# Python dynamic auto-completion and intellisense

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, dynamic-programming

[image]

Is there a way to get auto-completion and intellisense in python, when working dynamically like in the picture example?

I have spend hours trying to get make this work but no luck so far.

Comment: I don't see how this could work. Thie IDE would have to actually create and then track every instance of Person separately and update constantly.

Comment: PyLance is a **static** code analyzer

Comment: what do you mean by "dynamically"? Can you please give a clear description?

Comment: @user By "dynamically" I mean the instead of initializing a object constructor with static attributes I am passing them dynamically at the creation of an instance.

Comment: @Svenito So do you think is it possible? should I put my time to find a solution for this?

Comment: @rioV8 I mean, static analysis should be able to do this to some extent- at least within in the same scope and code paths where the members are added. (in theory- not in current actuality)

Comment: @user the OP can always submit a pull request for PyLance that implements what he wants

Comment: using objects this way is not very OOP, reasoning over code is impossible, proving the correctness of code is impossible

Comment: so some of your `Persons` have a `name` and some have a `gender` and some have a Harly motor cycle

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, why do you have such an idea? Can you describe your needs and why in detail?

Comment: @dinesh-hills I think It could be possible somehow. As mentioned by others. But i also agree very strongly with the statement that this is not a reasonable thing to try to achieve from an object oriented programming (OOP) standpoint. Your objects should be well defined as they give your application structure. If you're in need of a container that can contain any kind of object determined at runtime , just use a dictionary with key-value pairs.

Comment: Alright I get it, wanted to know it is possible, Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from GitHub:

> pylance is a static analyzer, so unfortunately none of the dynamic behavior will be supported.

link: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4333