# How does pandas.options auto completion work (VSCode)?

Tags: python, pandas, types, intellisense, pylance

Does anyone know how pandas' auto-complete for `option` works (at least in VSCode)?  For example,

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows
```

shows the type hint with ctrl + space and `pd.options.display.` shows `max_rows` among other options with ctrl+space.  From what I understand (see e.g., [Python dynamic auto-completion and intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76173336/python-dynamic-auto-completion-and-intellisense)), this should not be possible because options are registered at run time and rely on `getattr`: see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/52cb549f443f09727448251cfee53227c6bca9d2/pandas/core/config_init.py#L313-L399) for an example of runtime registration in `pandas` and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/52cb549f443f09727448251cfee53227c6bca9d2/pandas/_config/config.py#L453) for the exported `options` object, which is created dynamically based on the registration from what I can tell.

I must be missing something.  There must be some aspect of this I'm missing.  The type hints/autocomplete even both work within pandas' repo from what I can tell by checking it out.

Here is a screenshot of the autocomplete:

[image: autocomplete of display]

If I myself instantiate a `DictWrapper` around a dictionary (similar to but simpler than the `options` type), I don't get the ctrl+space autocomplete, which is expected and why I am so surprised at pandas.  They must be doing something different:

```py
class DictWrapper:

    d: dict[str, Any]

    def __init__(self, d: dict[str, Any], prefix: str = "") -> None:
        object.__setattr__(self, "d", d)

    def __setattr__(self, key: str, val: Any) -> None:
        self.d[key] = val

    def __getattr__(self, key: str):
        return self.d[key]

    def __dir__(self) -> list[str]:
        return list(self.d.keys())
    
d = DictWrapper({"foo": "bar"})
```

[image: type completion DictWrapper]

I apologize if this is a dumb question or has an obvious answer! First time posting (I think) so hopefully I followed the rules!

UPDATE:  So I tried something funny in the pandas repo, removing the "global" imports (i.e., `from pandas._config.config import options`) and using relative ones (`from .config import options`).  This seems to break the autocomplete, actually.  So I wonder if pylance has a custom pyi file in the closed source section of the tool...

Comment: it works perfectly fine, so not sure what the question is asking ?

Comment: the "dot" exposes the available methods and attributes that exist. So long as they are defined, they will be in the list.

Comment: My point is that there's no reason to think they should work.  The other stack overflow question points out that pylance contains a static type checker powering the intellisense autocomplete.  But `options` is dynamic because it involves registering different settings.  So there's no reason to think it should support autocomplete with a static type checker.  And yet, it does.

I'm trying to build something similar, and came across this as an example.